# Casting problem with Python ctypes module

Tags: python, ctypes

I am trying to interact with some Windows API using ctypes in Python. More specifically with ProJS: https://learn.microsoft.com/fi-fi/windows/win32/projfs/file-system-operation-notifications#how-to-specify-notifications-to-receive

The problem raises when I try to pass an array to the windows module.This  the structures I am using:

```
class PRJ_STARTVIRTUALIZING_OPTIONS(Structure):
  _fields = [('Flags', c_int),
             ('PoolThreadCount', c_uint),
             ('ConcurrentThreadCount', c_uint),
             ('NotificationMappings', POINTER(PRJ_NOTIFICATION_MAPPING)),
             ('NotificationMappingsCount', c_uint)]


class PRJ_NOTIFICATION_MAPPING(Structure):
  _fields = [('NotificationBitMask', c_int),
             ('NotificationRoot', LPCWSTR)]
```

And this is my code snippet to set a mapping. (Similar to the code example in C#):

```
virtualizationOptions = ProjectedFS.PRJ_STARTVIRTUALIZING_OPTIONS()
virtualizationOptions.NotificationMappingsCount = 0x0000001
mapping = ProjectedFS.PRJ_NOTIFICATION_MAPPING()
mapping.NotificationRoot = ""
mapping.NotificationBitMask = 0x0000001
virtualizationOptions.NotificationMappings = (ProjectedFS.PRJ_NOTIFICATION_MAPPING * 1)(mapping)
```

The notification mask that I am using is not being changed. So I am suspecting something is wrong with the way I am passing the array

Comment: `_fields_` not `_fields`.  Missing trailing underscore.

Comment: @MarkTolonen that was it! excelent. Had those 2 structures misspelled and didn't notice. Very appreciated